# process data from text file and convert into csv

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

In our organization, every month a few jobs will run and collect data on server level and it will find what is running on the server and also perform some checks. These files are text files and copied to one repository server.  The file name will be `<servername>_20200911.log`

This sample file checks for servers where postgreSQL is running.

```
Date Collected                  || 11-10-2020 03:20:42 GMT ||
Server Name                     || pglinux1             ||
Operating system                || RHEL                     || passed
OS Version                      || 6.9                      || passed
Kernel version                  || 2.6.32-735.23.1.el6      || passed
Kernel architecture             || x86-64                   || passed
Total Memory                    || 16 gig                   || passed
/opt/postgres fs free           || 32 gig                   || passed
/opt/postgres/data fs free      || 54 gig                   || passed
Is cron jobs exist              || yes                      || passed
Is postgres installed           || yes                      || passed
Postgres version >10            || no                       || failed
repmgr installed                || yes                      || passed
repmgr version  >4              || yes                      || passed
How may pg cluster running      || 3                        || Passed
pgbackrest installed            || yes                      || passed
```

We will get similar files for different technologies, like oracle, mysql, weblogic ...  Every month we  need to process these files and identify failed checks and work with the corresponding team. Now I am consolidating data for  all postgreSQL/oracle. In my case I will get lot of files and read each text file and convert data to cvs as below

```
Date Collected, server name, OPerating system , OS Version,Kernel version,Kernel architecture,Total Memory, /opt/postgres fs free,/opt/postgres/data fs free,Is cron jobs exist,    
11-10-2020 03:20:42 GMT,pglinux1, RHEL, passed, passed, passed, passed , passed , passed, passed passed, failed  
11-10-2020 03:20:42 GMT,pglinux2, RHEL, passed, passed, passed, passed , passed , passed, passed passed, failed  
11-10-2020 03:20:42 GMT,pglinux3, RHEL, passed, passed, passed, passed , passed , passed, passed passed, failed
```

Initially I thought, convert these text files into CSV and pick the second row from each file, consolidate it into one file. I failed with this attempt, since some file data is not consistent.  Now I am thinking to create a file called `servercheck.txt` with all the checks. Use this checks file to grep data in all files and print into a CSV file (one row per server).

```
#! /bin/bash
awk -v ORS='{print $0 ","} /tmp/servecheck.txt |sed 's/ *$//g' > serverchecks.csv
for file in `ls -lart *2020091t.log |awk '{print $9}'`
do  
     while read line
     do 
        grep "$line" $file |awk -F "||" '{print $3}' |awk -v ORS='{print $3 ","}' >> serverchecks.csv
     done < servercheck.txt
done
```

The above code is writing data in same row (heading and data).

I hope I have provided all necessary details. Please help us with code, recommendation, and the best approach to handle this issue.

Comment: Check your script with http://shellcheck.net . Fix all mistakes. [Do not use ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).  [Use `$(..)` instead of bnackticks \`](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Fix your awk syntax. Is there any reason you need leading spaces in your csv file?

Comment: the sample input file has 16 rows while the desired output 10 header columns and 9 data columns; could you a) verify the desired output you've posted and 2) how do you determine which rows from the source should be included as columns in the desired output?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I will check my code now and get back to you .

Comment: `and pick 2nd row from each file` - your sample output shows 3 lines from 2nd row and rest outputs from 3rd row. So second or third row? (Honestly, you should talk with the other side and tell them to output machine parsable format, most probably json)

Comment: @KamilCuk , initially i tried with code ``` BEGIN { FS="||" OFS="," } { printf "%s%s", (FNR>1 ? OFS : ""), $ARGIND } ENDFILE {     print ""     if (ARGIND < NF) {         ARGV[ARGC] = FILENAME         ARGC++     } } ```   for each file in a directory. i got one csv file for each text file which contain (hading  and a row of with acutal data). if follow the path, i ran in to another issues, since data is not consistent in all file.  so i keep 1st column values in a file called (servercheck.txt) and using the file to grep in actual files

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
for inputfile in *
do
  awk -F "\|\|" '
    { 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
      a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}   
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
     for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
     for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
        str=str" "a[i,j];
     }
    print str
   }
  }' $inputfile| sed 's/ \+ /,/g' > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$inputfile"
done
```

Edited as suggested by @Ed Morton

```
for inputfile in *
  do 
  awk -F "\|\|" '
   { 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
    a[NR,i] = $i
 }
 }   
  NF>p { p = NF }
  END {    
  for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
    str=a[1,j]
 for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
    str=str" "a[i,j];
 }
{gsub(/ \+ /,",",str); print str}
}
}' $inputfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$inputfile"
done
```

Comment: `awk '{print str}' | sed 's/ \+ /,/g'` = `awk '{gsub(/ \+ /,",",str); print str}'`. You never need a pipe to/from sed when you're using awk.